# Personalizar nome do arquivo em pdf feito no jaspersoft, java e spring

Tags: spring, jasper-reports, pdf

Tenho vários relatórios feitos no JasperSoft que geram PDF e quando gerados no Java, ao baixar o relatório no meu pc, ele esta como "document.pdf". Como faço para dar um nome diferente a este relatório, por exemplo "relatorio_clientes.pdf"?
Os relatórios foram montados pelo jaspersoft e a minha aplicação é em Java e spring para chamar o relatório faço o seguinte:

```
@GetMapping("/clientes")
public ModelAndView gerarRelatoriosClientes(@AuthenticationPrincipal UsuarioSistema usuarioSistema) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {

    HashMap<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    parametros.put("codigoEmpresa", usuarioSistema.getUsuario().getEmpresa().getCodigo());
    parametros.put("format", "pdf");
    return new ModelAndView("relatorio_clientes", parametros);
}
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Onde está o código utilizando o jasperReport que você cria o PDF?. Poste ele por favor

Comment: Assim, é um jrxml feito no jaspersoft, ele é muito extenso pra por todo aqui, segue o inicio e fim dele:

Comment: Na aplicação tem uma classe chamada de WebConfig, onde tenho toas as cofigurações, o metodo responsavel por detectar o japer é este:

Comment: JasperReportsViewResolver resolver = new JasperReportsViewResolver();
  resolver.setPrefix("classpath:/relatorios/");
  resolver.setSuffix(".jasper");
  resolver.setViewNames("relatorio_*");
  resolver.setViewClass(JasperReportsMultiFormatView.class);
  resolver.setJdbcDataSource(datasource);
  resolver.setOrder(0);
  return resolver;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O JasperReports possui o método `JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "nome_arquivo");`.

Onde o segundo argumento é o nome do arquivo. Vou colocar um exemplo:

```
public void relatorioTeste(String parametro) {
    parametros.put("parametro", parametro);
    try {
        JasperReport report = (JasperReport)JRLoader.loadObject(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/jasperteste/RelatorioTeste.jasper"));
        geraRelatorio(report);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        //tratar exceção
    }
}

private void geraRelatorio(JasperReport report) {
    try {
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, parametros, conexao);
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print, "nome_arquivo");
        con.close();
    } catch (JRException e) {
        //tratar exceção
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        //tratar exceção
    }
    parametros.clear();
}
```

Talvez a criação do PDF em seu sistema seja diferente, mas isso pode te ajudar.